# Why does my dragon tree have white spots and brown leaves?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, dracaena

My *Dracaena* has started to develop some brown leaf tips and white spots all over the plant, I transplanted the tree into a bigger pot about a week ago and ever since it’s been developing those spots. The tree has indirect sunlight and I water it once a week, but not with tap water. I don’t know the soil pH because I don’t have a tester since I’m new to gardening. I’ve moved it into a different room about a day ago to see if the room that it was in was somehow affecting it but no changes. The temperature stays at a constant 73-75 degrees inside my house. Please help me figure out what’s wrong.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Leaves] | [image: Whole plant and pot] |

Comment: Is the root material visible  on top  of the potting soil in the second photo actually roots  off the plant/s? And lastly, is that a pot with drainage holes, or a self watering pot?

Comment: No it’s not visible, That are just dead leaves from the soil, it’s a self watering but i don’t use the self watering part, I water it from the top and let it drain out

Comment: do you know what’s wrong? it has gotten worse the leaves  are brown on the first 2-3 inches on the tips

Comment: Another question or two - was this two plants you potted together, or did it always have two separate stems? What soil did you use to pot into?

Comment: Well i bought it like that, i’m pretty sure it’s two plants, I used compost and regular potting soil. I also have another dracaena from the same store, it is doing just fine so i don’t know what’s wrong with this one

Comment: It reminds me of a palm without enough manganese. I would suspect a pH issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you repotted into proper potting soil but added compost to it? If the compost was not produced using a hot aerobic system, it may have introduced pathogens into the soil mix - potting soil is sterilised to prevent this possibility. If you're unsure as to the production method of the compost,  it might be best to decant the plant, remove as much soil as possible without breaking the roots, then repot into a clean, well scrubbed pot just using potting soil on its own.

Check the plant and its leaves thoroughly (you may need a magnifying glass) for spider mites in case it's got an infestation - they can cause yellowing and streaking of leaves. Otherwise, you may not be watering enough - it should be watered when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, then watered well, with the excess allowed to drain away freely from the base. Otherwise, dry air can cause brown tips on these plants, but not usually the yellowing and streaking.